# Running latest docker version with snappy ubuntu core

Tags: ubuntu-core

I created a KVM virtual machine on my ubuntu 14.10 box using instructions at this link -

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/snappy#snappy-local

After installing docker and executing `docker --version` command, it is showing version as 1.3.3. However I am unable to find any such version of docker under docker release notes. So which version of docker is this exactly?

Also how can I upgrade to latest version (1.4.1) of docker?

Comment: Using a normal ubuntu version you could use a PPA or similar as suggested below (so Ubuntu Server would be suitable). But to update a package for Snappy Core you may need to package it yourself - there is some guidance on the snappy packaging system here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/packaging-format-apps/ https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/tutorials/build-snaps/

Comment: Both the links talk about snappy apps but as far as I know docker runs as a snappy framework on ubuntu core and not as an app. So looking for a step by step guide for upgrading docker to latest version.